# TinyMCE copy text+images from MS Word not working

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-4

Tried copying text+images from MS Word to TinyMCE editor. Text got copied but images didn't. While independently copying images, it is working. Is there any solution for this ? I have tried **paste_data_images:true**, but that too didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

In IE navigator is working fine and in google chrome and firefox not working with tinyMce LGPL license.
Need to buy the powerpaste plugin https://www.tinymce.com/pricing/.